# Cannot load custom controller action from link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, link-to

I'm a rails beginner and have been several hours now trying to figure out why my "generate new password" link, which was supposed to execute my custom update_password action inside my users controller, and then flash the password back on the screen (later i plan to send this by e-mail or sms, but for now this would do) keeps executing the create method/action...
I understand I have two POST methods for the users index screen...but cannot understand (since i even placed it first on the routes file) why create is the one that keeps getting executed. I know it doesn't go to the update method, because i filled it with debugger logging messages, which do not show up anywhere. (and the logging is active since i see the index method logging message)

Here is what I'm doing :

routes.rb file extract :

```
match 'users?user_id=(:user_id)', to: "users#update_password", via: :post, as: "users_update_password"
```

resources :users

rake routes (controller users)

```
users_update_password POST   /users?user_id=(:user_id)(.:format) users#update_password
            users GET    /users(.:format)                    users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                    users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)           users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                users#show
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                users#destroy
           signup        /signup(.:format)                   users#new
```

users_controller.rb

```
          def update_password
logger.info "Inside update_password"
logger.flush
password= generate_password()
logger.debug "Password is #{password}"
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
logger.debug "user is #{@user}"
if @user.update_attributes(password:password, password_confirmation:password)
  logger.info "inside the if"
   flash[:notice] = "New password for user #{@user.name}: #{password}"
   logger.debug "Flash is #{flash}"
   redirect_to users_path
else
  logger.debug "I am on else of update_password"
  flash[:alert] = "Name: #{@user.name} password: #{password}"
  render 'index'
end
```

end

```
def index
logger.info "Inside controller index method"
@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

end

_user.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
 | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" %>
 | <%= link_to "Generate new password", users_update_password_path(:user_id=>user.id), method: :post, confirm: "Are you sure? This will reset current password" %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might simplify things if you make this a member of your resource routes?

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post 'update_password'
  end
end
```

Then path helper probably looks like

```
link_to "Generate new password", update_password_user_path(user), method: :post
# POST. /users/:id/update_password
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. i did try this solution, but i just got a route error saying there was no route for GET update_password. I had read those guides, but didn't quite understand on how to achieve what i wanted. lee's answer proved right, but i still would like to understand the why's and abouts...and to know what would be the best practice here.

Comment: I left off the method post in the link to, added now, that should work

Comment: I've rebuilt it this way and it goes just fine. I'm choosing this answer instead, since the code is cleaner. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you use HTTP POST, the data is not sent in the URL.  Your route is looking for data in the URL, which is done via HTTP GET.  So if you want to use a POST, make your route something like:

```
post "users/update_password" => "users#update_password", :as => "users_update_password"
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick :-). I didn't quite understood the why though. What's the difference between the match and the post in the routes file? Are there any best practices on this subject?

Comment: "match", without specifying a "post" or "get" later on, will match any route that looks like that -- it's basically a catch-all for the URL that you specify.  Specifying "post" at the beginning is just shorter than writing: match "url", :to => "action", :via => "post"

Comment: ok, i guess that the "users/update_password" did the trick here then to access directly my custom method. Thank you very much !